# how to avoid creating multiple popup when defining in xaml?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, popup

I want to show a popup in a page on a event. I have added a popup in a page's definition. It works fine for the 1st time. But since Popup is not a part of visual-tree, the popup gets created again when visiting the page next time. how can I avoid this? the only option I know is to write a static popup in code-behind. But is there any way I can do this in xaml? (or may be in VM)

this is my code in XAML.

```
<Popup Grid.Row="2" x:Name="popup" IsOpen="{Binding VenueListOpen}">
                <ScrollViewer Height="600" Margin="0,0,0,20" Background="#55000000">
                    <StackPanel Width="{Binding DeviceWidth}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EventsList}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Margin="20,0" Background="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True, Converter={StaticResource EventRowBackgroundConverter}}">                                      
                                        <TextBlock Margin="20,5" FontSize="30" Text="Metlife stadium" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="20,5" Foreground="SkyBlue" Text="www.metlifestadium.com" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>                                        
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Popup>
```

Comment: Where exactly is your Popup located in the xaml markup? Have you tried to move it to Window.Resources?

Comment: @VladimirFrolov this is in page's root control. i don't know how to do use control as a resource. and what is window.Resource? is it Page.Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. May be there are better solution but this works for me:

in code behind, detach the binding by setting it to `null`. So whenever you move away the current `popup` will become orphan, and when u visit the page again, navigation will create new page as well as new popup up. but this time only new popup will appear, because the older popup is not in bound with `datacontext` so binding for `IsOpen` will not affect any older instance of that popup.

Comment: I am having same issue, but this doesn't sound right... In the end we'll end up with loads of orphan popups consuming memory? surely?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 as soon as any UI control goes off, it will be garbage-collected provided there is no reference bound to that UI control. (make sure to unhook any delegate, event handlers while moving away.)

Answer (score 0):

How about setting its `Visible` property to false or true when you enter the page?

Comment: but since the binding is applicable to each instance of the popup, each of those will get open/close at the same time. and the worst part is, the instances are not overlapped, they appear at different position.

Comment: So if im understanding correct, you have multiple instances of your popup showing? That makes very little sense seeing as you only declared it once. Maybe you could provide more context with your code? What control / form is your popup a child of?